# Using Zookeeper to dynamically distribute Kafka topic subscriptions to consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Say I have 500 Kafka topics I want to distribute evenly among N consumers and that the number of consumers varies over time, could I use Zookeeper to dynamically allocate topics based on the number of registered consumers?

I am not deeply familiar with Zookeeper but I think this is possible given how it's used for distributed consensus protocols. Something like creating a data node with the topics and registering consumers to divide them up but could this method avoid consumers having duplicate topics as well?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts

Comment: So, you want to manually assign consumers and not use consumer groups? Assignment might be easy, but you still have to track offsets

Comment: @OneCricketeer specifically I want to assign topics to Apache Flink jobs to consume messages and if one of the TaskManagers fails I want the topics to reassigned to the other workers. Maybe use predefined consumer groups with specific topics? I'm not sure if that's possible/able to be changed dynamically with the standard Kafka client

Comment: So, if you have extra tasks than total topic partitions, then natively, Kafka consumer groups will rebalance themselves. The downside is that you have idle resources being consumed by the Flink cluster

Comment: I have limited knowledge in Flink, but Spark has a retry policy for failed tasks, so you also wouldn't need to worry about that too much

Comment: Thanks I'll look into using groups then, I didn't know Kafka had built-in rebalancing